# How to add another value to a HTTP field in a POST request?

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a C# script in SSIS which sends data off to a 3rd party through their API (which is by far the worst API I've ever dealt with!).

Anyway, it is extremely sensitive to how it should receive data. The API receives CSV content, with the following working:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="values"; filename="name.txt"

"test1073R","2016-02-23T00:00","0.00","0.00"
```

But this one doesn't:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="values"

"test1073R","2016-02-23T00:00","0.00","0.00"
```

The difference being that the `filename="name.txt"` has to be sent.

This data is being sent directly from a variable- it is not written to a string first. Below is my code which creates the HTTP request, however I am unsure how to add `filename="name.txt"` to the request. Any ideas?

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var values = new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("customerid", Variables.BeonicCustomerId),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", Variables.BeonicUsername),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", Variables.BeonicPassword),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("values", dataSb.ToString())
        };

        foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
        {
            multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value),
                String.Format("\"{0}\"", keyValuePair.Key));
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add the whole content disposition in the following way:

```
multipartFormDataContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"values\"; filename=\"name.txt\"");
```

From what I understand from what you wrote, you need the file name as part of the Content-Disposition so you can add it through the Headers propery.